# Interleaving tuple

Tags: python, tuples

Define a function `interleaved_tuple_two` that takes two arguments, `tuple_a` and `tuple_b` that returns a tuple of interleaved values which interleave one value of `tuple_b` for every two values of `tuple_a`. Assuming `tuple_a` is always twice of `tuple_b`.

For example:

```py
tuple_a = (1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15)
tuple_b = (2,4,6,8)
```

`interleaved_tuple_two(tuple_a, tuple_b)` will return:

```
(1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 4, 9, 11, 6, 13, 15, 8)
```

Currently, I have this but it's incorrect. Not too sure how to improve on this

```py
def interleaved_tuple_two(tuple_a, tuple_b):
    return [val for pair in zip(tuple_a, tuple_b) for val in pair]
```

Comment: For a beginner I would recommend to make a simple for-loop over "range(0, len(tuple_b))" and collect the desired items with a bit of index arithmetic from the tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use zip with three lists, the first two have `tuple_a` skipping one value at a time but have different start positions, and then the third is `tuple_b`.

```
tuple_a = (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15)
tuple_b = (2, 4, 6, 8)

tuple_c = tuple(
    v
    for triple in zip(tuple_a[::2], tuple_a[1::2], tuple_b)
    for v in triple
)
print(tuple_c)
```

Another option would be to use an index and map it to the appropriate lookup:

```
tuple_c = tuple(
    v
    for i in range(len(tuple_b))
    for v in (tuple_a[i*2], tuple_a[i*2+1], tuple_b[i])
)
```

You could also use `itertools.chain` to avoid the comprehension:

```
from itertools import chain

tuple_a = (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15)
tuple_b = (2, 4, 6, 8)

tuple_c = tuple(chain(*zip(tuple_a[::2], tuple_a[1::2], tuple_b)))
print(tuple_c)
```